# If $x$ is an ordinal, then so is $x\,\bigcup\,\{x\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

I wish to show that $x$ is an ordinal, then so is $x\,\bigcup\,\{x\}$ (with $y<x$ for all $y\in x$).

I have seen a proof in Cameron's *Sets, Logic and Categories* (p.41), but I find it unsatisfactory. He writes:

> The set $a = x\,\bigcup\,\{x\}$ (with order as specified in the the statement of the theorem) has as sections all the sections of $x$ and one additional one, namely $a_x$. But since all the elements of $x$ are smaller than $x$, we have $a_x = x$.

I don't see why it necessarily follows from this that $a_x = x$. By definition, $a_x = \{y\in a : y\subset x\}$, so $a_x\subseteq x$, but this is different than $a_x = x$.

Comment: Cameron defines a section $a_y$ ($y\in a$) to consist in all the elements of $a$ which are less than $y$ (ordered by inclusion)

Comment: If $\subset$ is a *proper* inclusion, then Cameron is right.

Comment: @HanulJeon Can you explain?

Comment: You can see that $x\subseteq a_x\subsetneq x\cup\{x\}$. Then what must $a_x$ be?

Comment: @HanulJeon In my original post, I wrote $a_x=\{y\in a:y\subset x\}$, but the definition Cameron actually gives is $a_x=\{y\in a:y < x\}$. Does this make a difference?

Comment: If $\subset$ is a proper inclusion, then no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $y\in x$.  Since $x$ is an ordinal, this implies $y\subset x$.  So, $y$ is an element of $a$ such that $y\subset x$, which by definition means that $y\in a_x$.

Comment: I'm happy to mark this as correct, but can you see if my more formal answer (below) works?

Comment: Yep, it looks good.

Answer (score 1):

In my original post, I wrote $a_x=\{y\in a:y\subset x\}$, but the definition Cameron actually gives is $a_x=\{y\in a:y < x\}$. Does this make a difference?

Either way, it seems that:

$$\begin{align}
a_x &= \big\{y\in a:y<x\big\} \\
&= \big\{y\in x\cup\{x\}:y<x\big\} \\
&= \big\{y\in x:y<x\big\}\cup\big\{x\in\{x\}:y<x\big\} \\
&= x\,\cup\,\varnothing \\
&= x
\end{align}$$

where $\big\{x\in\{x\}:y<x\big\} = \varnothing$ because $x\nless x.$

Comment: It is not an actual answer but a question. You should add it to your question or write a new question rather than posting it as an answer.